# Error while update Mulesoft Runtime version to 4.2.1

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft, software-update

I am trying to update my mule run time to 4.2.1 in my anypoint studio and receiving the following error while installing the updates. If anybody faced a similar issue and could resolve it, please help.
[Run time update error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fDmV.png)

Comment: what is the version of your anypoint studio ?

Comment: Weirdly, Just after closing and restarting anypoint studio, it worked.

Comment: many a times you will notice weird behaviors with Anypoint Studio. what you can do is once in a while delete the .mule folder from your workspace and also you can add the following property -Dosgi.clean=true as the first line in the Anypoint studio config file (it will be a .ini file in the Anypoint studio home directory)

Answer (score 0):

The error is a read timeout. It could be a temporary error. Try repeating the operation again.